# Применение :hover для изменения фона в панели навигации

Tags: css, css3

Как при наведении на элемент шапки сделать так, чтобы подсвечивалась определённая область?
Код: `https://jsfiddle.net/denisario/2drn0nxt/`

Пример:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.header {
  background-color: #313030;
  height: 90px;
  width: 1250px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  top: 25px;
}

.menu ul {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
  padding-top: 40px;
  margin-left: 380px;
  font-weight: 600;
  position: absolute;
}

.menu li {
  display: inline;
}

.li-1 {
  padding-right: 65px;
  height: 90px;
  width: 90px;
}

.li-3 {
  padding-left: 48px;
  padding-right: 55px;
}

.li-1:hover {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="menu">
    <ul>
      <li class="li-1">home</li>
      <li class="li-2">portfolio</li>
      <li class="li-3">about us</li>
      <li class="li-4">contact</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: http://htmlbook.ru/css/hover

Comment: Оно выделяет не ту область, которую нужно

Comment: Оно выделяет ту область, которую Вы указали. Добавьте паддинги внутрь тега li и уберите их с контейнера

Comment: Так у каждого элемента списка разные паддинги

Comment: И что из этого?

Comment: Можете пример кода скинуть?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По бокам таким же образом пропишите паддинги до нужной формы

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.header {
  background-color: #313030;
  height: 90px;
  width: 1250px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  top: 25px;
}

.menu ul {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
  padding-top: 0px;
  margin-left: 380px;
  font-weight: 600;
  position: absolute;
}

.menu li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-top: 40px;
}

.li-1 {
  padding-right: 65px;
  height: 90px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 90px;
}

.li-3 {
  padding-left: 48px;
  padding-right: 55px;
}

.li-1:hover {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="menu">
    <ul>
      <li class="li-1">home</li>
      <li class="li-2">portfolio</li>
      <li class="li-3">about us</li>
      <li class="li-4">contact</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вместо уникальных классов нужно применять id, но в данном случае вообще они не нужны.

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.header {
  background-color: #313030;
  height: 90px;
  width: 1250px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  top: 25px;
}

.menu ul {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
  margin-left: 380px;
  font-weight: 600;
}

li {
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  height: 90px;
  line-height: 90px; /*вертикальное выравнивание*/
  text-align: center; /*горизонтальное выравнивание*/
  float: left;
}

li:hover {
  background-color: red;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="menu">
    <ul>
      <li>home</li>
      <li>portfolio</li>
      <li>about us</li>
      <li>contact</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```